# Cannot get the path with Pillow lib

Tags: python, path, python-imaging-library

I would like to get the path of an opened image with an URL.
Here is the code :

```py
response_api = requests.get(URL_GET_MUSIC_COVER.format(music_id, diff_name), stream=True)
image = Image.open(response_api.raw)
```

I do not want to store the image on my disk, that's why I open directly the image with the PIL lib.
If I do a `image.show()`, it opens with the default image viewer on my system, and I can see the path in my temp folder `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjj4hoa08.PNG`

This attribute 'filename' : [doc](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.filename)

It returns nothing.

I really need the path for the program I'm writing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you are loading the raw image from the memory, it's not saved anywhere at that point (no path exists). When you use the `show` function, it saves the image temporarily so the operating system's image viewer can show you the image.

Comment: You'll have to choose a path yourself with `image.save()` , if you'd like to replicate the `show` method's temporary path, you can use the `tempfile` module.

Comment: I guess I will use the save method, thanks